# YN560 IV with Yongnuo RF-603N II

Tags: wireless-flash

I'm trying to do off camera flash using the YN560 IV and RF-603N II but can't get the flash to work. If anyone is familiar with this particular gear, I'd love to have your input. I've seen a few answers to this situation using the YN560 III but there are a few differences.I'm using a Nikon camera if that matters.

I'm trying to use the flash off camera. The camera is in manual mode. Shutter speed 1/200, aperture is F8, ISO 100. I have the RF-603N II transceivers set on channel 1 although I've also tried putting all the channel switches in the on position. Both units were in TX mode The flash is on channel 1 and in TX mode.Basically I can't get the flash to fire off camera.

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to do that isn't working? Please describe what settings you have selected in the flash portion of your camera as well as what settings you have selected on the RF-603N II and the YN560 IV.

Comment: I'm trying to use the flash off camera. The camera is in manual mode. Shutter speed 1/200, aperture is F8, ISO 100. I have the RF-603N II transceivers set on channel 1 although I've also tried putting all the channel switches in the on position. Both units were in TX mode The flash is on channel 1 and in TX mode.Basically I can't get the flash to fire off camera. Let me know if any other info is helpful and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the flash in RX (receive) mode.

Answer (score 0):

TX = transmitter
RX = receiver

The on-camera unit has to be in TX mode, while the off-camera unit has to be in **RX** mode.  The YN-560IV can be used as either master or slave, and if it's set to TX, then you've got two masters and no slaves.

BTW, the RF-603N II, on a Nikon body, can be set to **TRX** if you want, it doesn't have to be in TX to be a transmitter.  In TRX mode, the transceiver can automatically sense whether it's attached to a camera hotshoe or whether a flash has been attached to its hotshoe, so it can autoswitch to be either a transmitter or receiver as required.  The TX mode is for non-Canon/Nikon camera bodies or in-hand use where the signals on the camera hotshoe won't cause the autoswitching to happen.